# reCAPTCHA not working in IE8

Tags: php, internet-explorer, captcha, recaptcha

reCAPTCHA (Zend_Service_ReCaptcha) is not working in IE 8 on our site.

Look at [this web site](https://forum.esfcr.cz/registration.htm).
Does anyone know why? It is working elsewhere including FF,Opera, etc.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

It is an `https` page, and the images and other items for reCaptcha are delivered via `http` and get blocked.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer but, why it is working in other browsers ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question; *Is there anyway to enable HTTPS for reCAPTCHA?*

I fixed it, just added `array('ssl' => true)` to params like this:

```
$recpatcha = new Zend_Service_ReCaptcha(
                '6Jd_ArXXXXXXXXXtdsT7zC69uy_X8rKcJWlMq9eK',
                '6Jd_AXXXXXXXXXXv_n5lMQ3OasSoHufjWndQ59ny',
                array('ssl' => true),
                array ('theme' => 'white', 'custom_translations' => array(
                    'instructions_visual' => gettext("Opíšte dvě slová"),
                    'instructions_audio' => gettext("Opíšte dvě slová")));
```